# Test Django-Rest custom field

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to test a custom field that is in an internal shared Python package **with no django** settings file (as there is not django app). When I run my tests I get the following error.

```
tests/test_fields.py:3: in <module>
    from rest_framework.validators import ValidationError
../../../.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/validators.py:14: in <module>
    from rest_framework.compat import unicode_to_repr
../../../.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/compat.py:107: in <module>
    from django.contrib.postgres import fields as postgres_fields
../../../.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/postgres/fields/__init__.py:1: in <module>
    from .array import *  # NOQA
../../../.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/postgres/fields/array.py:3: in <module>
    from django.contrib.postgres import lookups
../../../.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/postgres/lookups.py:4: in <module>
    from .search import SearchVector, SearchVectorExact, SearchVectorField
../../../.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/postgres/search.py:47: in <module>
    class SearchVector(SearchVectorCombinable, Func):
../../../.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/postgres/search.py:50: in SearchVector
    _output_field = SearchVectorField()
../../../.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py:172: in __init__
    self.db_tablespace = db_tablespace or settings.DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE
../../../.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py:56: in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
../../../.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py:39: in _setup
    % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
E   django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

Is there anyway to suppress the need for loading the settings? I'm simply trying to test the logic of the field.

```
class FMIDField(Field):

    VALID_CHARS = '[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}'

    default_error_messages = {
        'invalid_type': 'FMID must be a string',
        'invalid_characters': 'FMID must be 8 characters long and consist only of a-z, A-Z and 0-9'
    }

    def is_valid_chars(self, data):
        prog = re.compile(self.VALID_CHARS)
        return prog.fullmatch(data)

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        if not isinstance(data, str):
            self.fail('invalid_type')

        if not self.is_valid_chars(data):
            self.fail('invalid_characters')

        return data

    def to_representation(self, value):
        return value
```

**EDIT** for clarity

The python package this is being written and tested in has no Django settings module as it is supposed to be used in Django applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should include the following line in your file

```
import os

import django

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "PROJECT_NAME.settings")
django.setup()
```

**EDIT**

Try [this](http://hirokiky.org/tech/create_django_library.html) guide

Comment: The issue is that there isn't a django settings module as this is effectively a 3rd party library that is shared over the organization and doesn't actually have a django application in it.

Comment: I have added a link, please try it and see

Comment: That looks like it might work. Give me some time to attempt it.

Comment: Added that to the top of my test file. Thank you.

Comment: Glad I could help. :)